# Applescript: want frontmost Mail window

Tags: applescript

I'm writing an applescript to select several mailboxes in my main Mail window.  I have two message viewer windows, as shown here:

[image]

And I have the following code:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set frontViewer to front message viewer
    set selectedBoxes to selected mailboxes of frontViewer
end tell
```

When I run it, I get the result: `{mailbox "Mailboxes/Pending" of application "Mail"}`

Clearly Mail is being a moron here (not that I'm surprised).  What do I have to do to beat it into submission?

Mail vsn 9.3 (build 3124), running on El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: Same code is working fine for me, as expected : I get the list of the 2 mail boxes {inbox, sent mailbox}. Used with Mail version 9.3 (build 3124) on El Capitain. I also tried selected other mail boxes with each time correct result.

Comment: That's so weird, I have Mail 9.3 (3124) and nothing I do (click on other message viewer, click on original message viewer // quit and relaunch Mail) causes it to give me the right result.  OS 10.11.6 BTW, should have mentioned that.  Can you please try bringing the second message viewer (Pending, in my case) to the front and seeing if it still gets it right?

Comment: I also have 10.11.6. I am not sure to understand what you're doing. I tried with 1 message viewer open, then with 2 message viewers, then switching from one to next, with or without a separate message window open. in all cases, I get the selected boxes with the script.

Comment: OK, obviously I'm cursed.  Thanks for trying to help! :-)